# Raspberry pi3 and odoo image

Tags: pi-3, pi-2

Every time I use odoo posbox image on the raspberry, I can't use the sudo command, did I miss something?

[image: Odoo posbox image]

Answer (score 1):

I am using posbox image in pi in Linux. You are using wrong command. Don't need to use command : **sudo apt-get update** Here "**update**" command won't work. That's why you are getting base error. Try with some else command. Because "**sudo**" is working in pi.

Answer (score 1):

In your picture it is the **Pi** part of the command that bash is complaining about.

The `sudo` command gives the current user root privileges and does not need to be told what user you are.  You can state the user with `sudo -u user` If you do not want to be root (for example www-data).

See [here](http://researchhubs.com/post/computing/linux-cmd/sudo-command.html) for a quick overview of sudo and [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/linux-users-and-groups/) for an overview of users and groups.

One minor point - if you are using the command line to update, it’s now better to use **apt** than **apt-get** as it gives more feedback.  apt-get is now being used for automated updates.

A simple way to bring the system up to date is:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
```

This updates the repository list and if (and ONLY if) that has run fine, downloads and automatically installs the latest versions from the repository.